# __builtin_return_address returns null for index >0?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to get the return address of the caller function. I'm using `__builtin_return_address()` funtion, but if I give index value greater than 0 it is returning `NULL`.

Please help me with this or tell me any other function to get the same.

Comment: *Why* do you use it? What's your aim?

Comment: "This function should only be used with a nonzero argument for debugging purposes." If you need a stack trace, there are other functions available.

Comment: @Deduplicator I need to store the return address of the caller function.

Comment: Please explain what motivates your question. Why do you need the return address of the caller function? What will you do with it? Show more code please, so edit your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26842066/841108) to a related question.

[`__builtin_return_address`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) is [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and processor specific (also available in *some* versions of [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) on *some* processors with *some* -lack of- optimizations), and documented as

> On some machines it may be impossible to determine the return address of any function other than the current one

The compiler might optimize a function (e.g. when it is compiled with `-fomit-frame-pointer`, or for [tail-calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), or by function [inlining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function)) without the relevant information.

So probably you are getting `NULL` because the information is not available!

Comment: Thanks!! Can you tell me any other function which gives the return address of the function which is not processor specific or works on ARMv7.

Comment: Probably, the information is not available. So no way to get something that does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to compiler optimisation reasons (which IMO is the most likely reason for the issue you're facing), the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) states quite plainly:

> Calling this function with a nonzero argument can have unpredictable effects, including crashing the calling program. As a result, calls that are considered unsafe are diagnosed when the `-Wframe-address` option is in effect. Such calls should only be made in debugging situations.

As Basile said, since it's a compiler builtin (read: very processor specific and a bad idea to use) the behaviour is **exceptionally** loosely defined (as it is not required by any standards and does not have to make any guarantees).

Just use [`backtrace(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html), it's POSIX-compliant and doesn't rely on compiler builtins.