# &((struct name *)NULL -> b) in printf statement

Tags: c, struct, casting, offsetof

I found this code sample in a book, but I am unable to understand the expression in printf statement.
and this program compiles successfully giving output as 4.
kindly advise...

```
void main(){
    unsigned char c;

    typedef struct name {
      long a;
      int b;
      long c;
    }r;

    r re = {3,4,5};
    r *na=&re;

    printf("%d",*(int*)((char*)na + (unsigned int ) & (((struct name  *)NULL)->b)));
}
```

Comment: You know `main` has a return-type of `int` in C (and C++)?

Comment: This exact program was posted 3 years ago, I guess it is a common book!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets start from the last line:

```
printf("%d",*(int*)((char*)na + (unsigned int ) & (((struct name  *)NULL)->b)));
```

Lets interpret:

```
(unsigned int ) & ((    (struct name  *)NULL)->b )
```

Is actually casting `& ((   (struct name  *)NULL)->b )` into a `unsigned int`.

`& ((   (struct name  *)NULL)->b )` is the address (i.e it gives a pointer to):

```
((  (struct name  *)NULL)->b )
```

Which is actually the offset of `b` (as `name.b`) from NULL (0), which is 4 bytes (assuming a `long` is 4 bytes) and converted to a pointer of int, gives you 2 (assuming `int` is 2 bytes).

If instead of `NULL` it would have been a pointer to `0xFFFF0000`, then `&(ptr->b)` would have been `0xFFFF0002`. But it more like `&(0 -> b)` so its `0x00000002`.

So, `(unsigned int ) & ((   (struct name  *)NULL)->b ) == 2` (or maybe 1, or maybe 4, depending on the machine).

The rest is simple: `*(int*)((char*)na + 2` will point to `re->b`. *So it should print 4* (what have been initialized in the code, `r re ={3,4,5};`).

P.S: even if  `(unsigned int ) & (( (struct name  *)NULL)->b ) != 2` (maybe it's 1, 4 or 8) - it should still print 4 because it then uses the same offset to get the value.

Comment: Be aware that this construct invokes UB though.

Comment: @Deduplicator Is `((  (struct name  *)NULL)->b )` undefined behavior? It actually seems pretty well defined for me. Can you point me to a link that specifies it?

Comment: @MarkSegal: It is doing pointer-arithmetic on a null pointer, which is simply illegal. Pointer arithmetic is only defined for pointers to a valid object, and only if it does not stray beyond the bounds of the underlying object (the pointer past an object is explicitly allowed though).

Comment: @MarkSegal: it might be unspecified undefined behavior, even if it practically works everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

`re` is a local variable of type `r`, i.e. a `struct name`; it is usually allocated on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

`na` is a pointer to `re`.

`(unsigned int) & (((struct name  *)NULL)->b)` might be [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (but I am not sure), but most compilers would compile that to the offset -in bytes- of field `b` (like `offsetof` does, see [offsetof(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/offsetof.3.html)). On my machine that might be 8.

`(char*)na +`  the above offset is often the same address as `&re.b`

You dereference that pointer, which practically is `&re.b`

I feel that your code might not be standard compliant (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840953/how-can-iterate-the-stack-frames-manually-in-c/26842066#26842066) for some argumentation; there might be hypothetical machines & C implementations where `NULL` is not an all-zero-bits word, I know no such implementations), but on all machines I know about, it should print the value of field `re.b`

Comment: thanks @Basile .... lets stick to machines we know about then... :)

Comment: @HimanshuSourav: http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html Just so you know some more machines ;-)

Comment: @Deduplicator: but these old XX-th century machines exist only in museums!

Comment: Just about. Which is why one can disregard a not-all-bits-zero null-pointer in practice, mostly. The UB in the pointer-arithmetic though, that can still bite you on modern machines, depending (mostly) on your implementation.

Answer (score 4):

The code:

```
(unsigned int ) & (((struct name  *)NULL)->b))
```

is intended to obtain the count, in bytes, of how far from the start of a `struct name` the variable `b` is.

There is a standard way to do this: `offsetof(struct name, b);`  . The person who wrote this code either was not aware of `offsetof`, or was attempting to teach something (although that may be a case of the blind leading the blind).

The code causes undefined behavoiur by dereferencing a null pointer, however common compilers may accept it without triggering an error, probably because compiler developers know that there is existing code out there like this.

---

The rest of the code is straightforward; it points to the start of the struct; advances by that many bytes, and reads an int from that location; which is of course the same as just reading `b` directly.

Comment: Technically the code is *not* derefenrencing the `NULL`  pointer. But I still feel it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have started a new question for whether this is actually UB although on first reading of C11 it's not looking good